# Suggest good ERD tool with UML notation

Tags: erd

I need to design an ERD with UML notation, can anyone recommend a tool that does this.

Comment: https://help.drawerd.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparx [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/?gclid=CJmwm96Jj64CFYgmtAodUnR4dw) is a UML tool with a database modelling function.  It's not terribly expensive and pretty UML centric.  It also has some pretty good extensibility features if you're that way inclined.